# Multiple sorting for fields not working on Parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, sorting, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

When multiple values are passed to descending function in Parse cloud code javascript API, the query is not sorted completely. It ignores the second sorting parameter field.

Example:

`query.descending('createdAt, playCount');`

The query is sorted with createdAt but playCount is ignored. The Parse forum says its a bug and they working on fixing it. I have tried the following but not successful.

`query.ascending('-createdAt, -playCount');`

Does anyone know a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only place on parse.com where I see anything about this [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/multiple-sorts-on-query) on their dormant q/a support.

If you read the small print in the comments there, it turned out that the acceptable format is very brittle, disallowing whitespace.  Given that, try:

```
query.descending('createdAt,playCount');  // deleted the blank after the comma
```